# How to print a text backwords using recursion?

Tags: c++, class, recursion

```
char Text::toReverse(Text t1, int t) const
{
    if (t1.bufferSize == 1)
        return ' ';
    if (t == (t1.bufferSize) - 1)
        return ' ';
    cout << t1.buffer[(t1.bufferSize) - 2 - t];
    return toReverse(t1, t + 1);
}
```

There's a Text class that has the private members `char* buffer` which is a null-terminating sequence of characters and bufferSize which is the length of the string.

I got this code by physically writing it out.  It makes sense to me on paper, which is why I don't know why the code keeps crashing.  I try to debug it but it won't let me continue because of some error handling problem.

Comment: May I suggest that you add print statements for bufferSize,bufferSize - 2, and bufferSize - 2 - t. Check if any of those become negative, or outside the size of the string.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "some error handling problem" has all the information you need. Pause there and inspect the stack with your debugger of choice.

Comment: I think this may be of use https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Quentin This isn't a stack, and I just said that I keep trying to debug it but it won't let me; it keeps giving me errors.

Comment: @user889742 That's a good idea!  I'll try that.

Comment: @EmilyLerman the function call stack, not the "stack" data structure :) -- Maybe you should try and get help about that debugger issue instead then, because it will only get more troublesome when your issues get more complex.

Comment: @UKMonkey I've done this already

Comment: @Quentin This is the first time I've ever had an issue with this debugger :( I'll post the  error I keep having.  Stupid Visual Studio...

Comment: The purpose of a debugger is *not* to fix the values and continue. It is to determine *why* the values were wrong *in the first place*, so you can edit the program so they *don't go wrong* next time

Comment: @Quentin It keeps saying "access violation writing location" and a memory location.  I keep pressing "break" and then continue (to continue to the next line in my code) and the error keeps showing up.  I've never had this problem before.

Comment: @Caleth I know...

Comment: You should verbose what you want to do before writing code. For example here you would want { Return if string is empty. Print last character of string. Remove last character from string. Repeat whole process for modified string }. Going from here it is not difficult to spot that you code snippet does not do what you intent it to do and where you should modify it.

Comment: @EmilyLerman that's not a debugger issue, that's actually the bug in your code. Your program is trying to access memory it doesn't own, so the kernel won't let it continue. Just break and you'll be sat on the line where that happened, and you can work out why it did. If you see a *huge* callstack, that's a stack overflow, and you should check why your algorithm is stuck in an infinite recursion.

Comment: @AndrewKashpur I did that... I wrote that I did that in my question

Comment: @Quentin So it's just stuck in an infinite loop?  That makes sense (idk why it's doing that but at least I know why my program hates me now).  I'll definitely look into that.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you get "access violation writing location", it's not caused by this function since it doesn't write to any memory.

There's nothing obviously wrong with it, but that's mostly because the arithmetic for reading an array backwards gets confusing.

To recursively print a string in reverse, it is simpler to first print the "rest" of the characters in reverse, then print "this" character.
Stop when you've reached the end of the string.

It's very unclear why the function returns a `char` if it's supposed to print a string, so this function doesn't:

```
void Text::toReverse(Text t1, int t) const
{
    if (t < t1.bufferSize)
    {
        toReverse(t1, t + 1);
        cout << t1.buffer[t];
    }
}
```